# I am trying to use $TBS->LoadTemplate to load my template file stored in Google Cloud storage

Tags: opentbs

It gives an error TinyButStrong Error OpenTBS Plugin: The End of Central Directory Record is not found. The same template file does work when i load it directly on the Google App Engine webserver where the tbs plugin is. Is it not possible to have the template loaded from a different URL? I can't put it on App Engine because its too big.

Comment: This error message means that the binary header of the ZIP container is not as expected. Your template file is may be corrupted. You should open it as a binary file in order to check the header. Otherwise try to open it with 7-zip (or other). What is the document type of your template ?

Comment: Hi! I thought it was something to do with not being able to use it correctly if it is stored in separate cloud storage because i moved a working one from the webserver to cloud storage and it gave the same error.  It is PPTX files. The new one is so big it doesn't fit on Google App Engine limits so i had to put it in cloud storage

Comment: It just can't handle the template being on the separate cloud storage even though it is set as a public file. I've verified they are all working templates on the web server, but not in Google Cloud. I'm going to try to move to different web server.

Comment: @Skrol29, i moved it to other servers and it fails with the same error. But they do work from within the same server file system. Are there any other things that i have to change or move to be able to support the template being on a different server? In your experience, should it be able to work if the only thing changing is the URL and location of the template file to another storage location?

Comment: I need some technical details in order to reproduce the problem. What is the code that brings this message. and what is the path of the template file ?

Comment: The template file is stored at a url like $template = "[https://storage.cloud.google.com/xxxxx.appspot.com/tbs/my_template.pptx](https://storage.cloud.google.com/xxxxx.appspot.com/tbs/my_template.pptx)". It fails with TinyButStrong Error OpenTBS Plugin: The End of Central Directory Record is not found. If i move the same template file to within the file system like $template = "tbs_templates/my_template.pptx" where i have the php code running for TBS template engine "tbs/tbs_class.php" and its plugin "tbs/tbs_plugin_opentbs.php" it works fine.

Comment: It fails at $TBS->LoadTemplate($template, OPENTBS_ALREADY_UTF8) when it tries to load the external template file. I did try moving the working template file to more than one different external URL. So i need to understand if i am just missing something that needs to be added or changed for an external url vs an internal url or if an external url for the template file is just not supported. To replicate the problem, just take a working pptx template file and move to an external location and change the template URL requested.

Comment: At this point you are not sure about the contents you get using the URL.You have to check the binary contents. It may contains a PHP error, or a PHP notice. You can check doing something like `$contents = file_get_contents($url); file_put_contents($local_path, $contents);`

Comment: I have it figured out, it is not working when google authentication is required. I really thought i had tested and ruled that out but must have got something crossed. Can you tell me how to open it as a binary file in order to check the header on a Mac?

Comment: just as mentioned above